# how to italicize part of a string for a flex list/dataprovider?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

how do i make half the string become italic after the new line(\n)?  doesnt work :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application creationComplete="populate()" minHeight="600" minWidth="955"               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable]
        public var listOfPeople:ArrayCollection;

        public function populate():void
        {
            var testData:String = "Test\<i>ntest</i>,Test\ntest\ntest";
            listOfPeople = new ArrayCollection(testData.split(","));
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:List dataProvider="{listOfPeople}" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it. if anyone wants to know how i did it for datagrid:

```
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Rooms">


                        <s:itemRenderer>
                            <fx:Component>
                                <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                    <s:VGroup>

                                    <s:Label text="{data.Rooms}"
                                             height="100%"
                                             right="10"
                                             verticalAlign="middle"
                                             fontWeight="bold"
                                             fontStyle="italic"/>
                                        <s:Label text="{data.Rooms}"
                                                 height="100%"
                                                 right="10"
                                                 verticalAlign="middle"
                                                 fontWeight="bold"
                                                 fontStyle="italic"/>
                                    </s:VGroup>
                                </s:GridItemRenderer>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </s:itemRenderer>

                    </s:GridColumn>
```

similiar can be done with list etc

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex4_05.html